# Добавить инфу в БД используя PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Всем привет.

У меня есть форма который в принципе должен добавить информацию через админку в БД.

Я  только только использую PDO (да и саму PHP тоже) поэтому строго не ругать 99% кода не я писал.

В БД создал таблицу category и 3 свойства id (автоинкремент) name и image навяский пожарный скажу что сравнение там стоит `latin1_swedish_ci`   в многих ресурсах используют `utf8_general_ci` но я думаю это не столь критично.

Форма такого типо

**HTML**

```
<form action="categories.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <fieldset>
         <label for="name">Name:</label>
         <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" placeholder="name">
            <label for="image">Image:</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="Image"/>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Add Category</button>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

в **DB.php** у меня такой обьектно ориентированный **PDO** код

```
     Class Database {

         private $link;

         public function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
         }

         private function connect(){
            $config = require_once "config.php";//тут подключаем config.php

            $dsn = "mysql:host=".$config["host"].";dbname =".$config["db_name"].";"; //тут используем настройки написанные в config.php

            $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $config["username"], $config["password"]);

            return $this;
         }

         public function execute($sql){
            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

            return $sth->execute();
         }
         public function query($sql){
            $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

            $sth->execute();

            $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($result === false){
                return [];
            }
            return $result;
         }
     }

$db = new Database();
```

Также есть **config.php** для дополнении к **DB.php**

```
return [
    "host" => "localhost",
    "db_name" => "razmovar",
    "username" => "root",
    "password" => ""

];
```

И соответственно часть **categories.php** где я хочу добавить файлы полученные из формы в БД

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ //если кнопка submit нажата
        $name = $_POST["name"]; 


        $image = $_FILES["Image"]["name"];
        $admin = "Макс";

        if(empty($name)){ //если полья name пусто выдать ошибку сессии которые внизу потом перенаправитсья в эту страницу

            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "all fields must be field up";
            redirect_to("categories.php");

            exit;
        } else if(strlen($name) > 40){ //nесли имя категории содержит символов больше чем 40 вывести ошибку сессии и опять  перенаправитсья в эту страницу

            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "category name can't be more than 40 symbol's";
            redirect_to("categories.php");
            exit;

        } else {
            global $db; //вызываем глобально переменную $db
            $db->execute("INSERT INTO `category` (name,image) VALUES('{$name}','{$image}')"); //добавляем в таблицу category значение полученные из переменных name и image

                if($db){ //если добавлено то сообшения сессии что все успешно добавлено 
                    $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Category added succesfully";
                    redirect_to("categories.php");
                }   else {//иначе ошибка
                    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Something went wrong";
                    redirect_to("categories.php");
                }
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том что каждый раз он пишет что `category added succesfully` (категория удачно добавилось) то есть доходит то части где **if($db)** и тут выводитсья **true** но когда я смотрю в БД там пусто ничего не добавилось ПОЧЕМУ ТАК помогите уже три дня не могу решить ..

Испробовал все

вместо этого `$db->execute("INSERT INTO`category`(name,image) VALUES('{$name}','{$image}')");`

кода писать ТАК..

```
$db->execute("INSERT INTO `category` (name,image) VALUES('$name','$image')");
```

Или так

```
$db->execute("INSERT INTO category (name,image) VALUES('$name','$image')");
```

Разные эксперементы делал с этой строкой но ничего не помогло .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if($db){` - А в `$db`-то у вас класс.

Нужно так:

```
$db = $db->execute("INSERT INTO `category` (name,image) VALUES('{$name}','{$image}')");
if($db){ ... }
```

Или так:

```
if($db->execute("INSERT INTO `category` (name,image) VALUES('{$name}','{$image}')")) { ... }
```

Или так:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `category` (name,image) VALUES('{$name}','{$image}')";
if($db->execute($sql)) { ... }
```

---

Не добавляется из-за этой строки:

```
dsn = "mysql:host=".$config["host"].";dbname =".$config["db_name"].";"
```

Должно быть так:

```
dsn = "mysql:host=".$config["host"].";dbname=".$config["db_name"].";"
```

Никаких пробелов, ничего лишнего.

Comment: Не стоит делать без подготовки выражения, напрямую запрос в базу. Чревато последствиями.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущий комментарий - само существование ответов с использованием склеенных вручную SQL-запросов угрожает мировому сообществу.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский -.- Не знаю куда мой предыдущий коммент делся на эту тему, НО мы тут обычно помогаем решить проблему (вне зависимости на сколько она грамотна, правильна, логична и т.д.). Если вы заговорили об правильности, то конкретно в нашем случае мы пояснили уже автору про безопасность (в ответе ниже). А придираться можно вечно: с БД лучше работать через `ORM`, не использовать `global`, логику запросов вынести в модель и т.д. я вечно так могу.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Если вы принципиально считаете что нужно давать правильные (в глобальном плане) ответы. То я ни в коем случае Вам не запрещаю это делать и оставлять свою версию, даже если вопрос решен, более того, если ответ будет достаточно полон я оценю его за старания.

Answer (score 3):

А где пишет-то? Вот это

> category added succesfully

Это ж вроде в сессию пишется....

Как проверяете БД? Перезайти не пробовали в БД? Мож браузер просто тупит?

И вообще откуда код?? Переменные, мне кажется, не проходят проверку на иньекцию, сырой код-то!!!

Инсертить вот так надо:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES (:name,:email,:username,:password)");
            $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: я имел ввиду вот эти проверки: $query->bindParam

Comment: @Demon__ANT ваш код действительно подвержен инъекциям, но вам нужно крутить скорей в сторону `bindValue`, а не `bindParam`. https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @Manitikyl а я думал в PDO от sql иньекции ты зашищен =( спс огромное еще раз

Comment: @Demon__ANT защищен, если использовать `bindValue` и `bindParam`

Comment: @Manitikyl аа так вот оно как O.o

Comment: Кстати, на том же гитхабе миллиард товарищей также бездумно используют PDO без этих банальных проверок, да еще и называя свои скрипты "С защитой от инъекции"...))) Кстати, bindValue или bindParam - это все одного поля ягода, для типового в вашем случае применения...

Answer (score 1):

Скажу свое мнение, что инженеры не дураки. 
По поводу того что на данном этапе городить классы которые будут выполнять работу с БД. 
Я не заморачиваюсь и пишу на процедурном. Не делаю никаких классов. Для этого есть RedBeanPhp. ЛУчше раз новичек как я, то я для начала изучаю как вообще с этим работать. Для инъекций я использую примерную запись.

```
$save = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `name_table` (`id_column`, `name_column`) VALUES (NULL, ?)");
$save->execute(array($_POST['id_column'], $_POST['name_column']));
```

Далее нужно разобраться с кодировкой если работаете с UTF-8 то и таблицам нужно задавать utf8_general_ci. иначе будут крокозябры если не городить трехэтажный код.
Попробуйте для начала создавать и закрывать соединение с бд, а потом уже это дело все запихивать в классы. Я не думаю что у вас проект размером с яндекс.

Comment: спасибо проект маленкий и я посмотрел один старый урок по php там и про PDO не было когда я выкладывал свой код мне сказали что это очень древний код php 5.3 и оно очень уязвимо к SQL иньекциям потом я с работу взял тестовый маленький проект и начал его писать но для того чтобы его не сломал какой то школник мимо проходящий я решил использовать PDO даже если у меня нету опыта и в youtube наткнулсья на урок где парень пишет используя классы и поддумал что это хорошое решение за одно и в php с ООП познакомлюсь вот как то так.

Comment: Да я тоже так пытался делать. Потом понял, что с этого не стоит знакомиться с ООП. Я как то записывал урок по RedBeanPhp связи многие ко многим но потом перешел на чистый PDO. люди улучшают а при возможности если надо и так ломанут. Поэтому сейчас нет смысла заморачиваться с безопастностью, лучше практику улучшать. Весь материал для изучения беру на пхп.нет там все описано и расписано довольно внятно и собственно разработчики пхп дают дельные советы.